# How can I pass an Integer value from a .cc file to .tcl file, when using ns2?

Tags: tcl, ns2, cc

I am counting packets using a variable in .cc file. 
Now, I want to get that value in my .tcl script, store it in some variable  and perform some operation on it?
How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few options, depending on how you've done the binding between your code and Tcl. For example, you can use `Tcl_NewIntObj()` to convert your value to a Tcl value that you can pass as an argument to a Tcl command, or you could use [`Tcl_LinkVar()`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclLib/LinkVar.htm) to make a variable in your C++ code (which ought to be long-lived, so often a global) expose itself as a Tcl variable.

```
// The interp is the interpreter context, which might come from Tcl_CreateInterp or might
// be handed to you by callback, depending on what you're doing.

Tcl_LinkVar(interp, "myVarName", (char *) &yourIntVariable, TCL_LINK_INT);
```

Once you've done that, reading the `myVarName` variable on the Tcl side will read from your variable until you `Tcl_UnlinkVar()` to break the coupling.

Comment: `Tcl_NewIntObj` is more for if you're going to pass the value as an argument or write it to a Tcl variable directly.